# Unable to upload binary to iTunes connect using Xcode 8.3

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to iTunes connect for two days but I'm continuously getting an error saying "Operation Failed". Please anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upload your binary with Application Loader instead of Xcode. Application loader will upload you binary to ItunesConnect quickly.

Comment: Thanks for answer am gonna to implement it.